# How to swap items instead of adding into the same container?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the react library dazzle https://github.com/Raathigesh/dazzle and the default add method allows it such that when one widget is dragged and dropped to another container the container expands to hold both widgets. Would it be possible to have it such that the widgets swap. ex. drag A to container B, widget B now moves to container A and widget A is now in container b. Any help would be great:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Dashboard, { addWidget } from 'react-dazzle';


import Header from './Header';
import EditBar from './EditBar';
import Container from './Container';
import AddWidgetDialog from './AddWidgetDialog';
import CustomFrame from './CustomFrame';


import BarChart from './widgets/BarChart';
import LineChart from './widgets/LineChart';
//import ApprovalList from './ApprovalList';
import DataTable from './tableWidget';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';


import 'react-dazzle/lib/style/style.css';


import '../styles/custom.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

      widgets: {
        BarWidget: {
          type: BarChart,
          title: 'Bar Graph Widget',
        },
        ApprovalWidget: {
          type: DataTable,
          title: 'Order Approval',
        },
        LineWidget: {
          type: LineChart,
          title: 'Trend Graph Widget',
        },


      },

      layout: {
        rows: [{
          columns: [{
            className: 'col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
            widgets: [{key: 'LineWidget'}],
          }],
        }, {
          columns: [{
            className: 'col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8',
            widgets: [{key: 'BarWidget'}],
          }, {
            className: 'col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4',
            widgets: [{key: 'ApprovalWidget'}],
          }],
        }],
      },
      editMode: false,
      isModalOpen: false,
      addWidgetOptions: null,
    };
  }


  onRemove = (layout) => {
    this.setState({
      layout: layout,
    });
  }


  onAdd = (layout, rowIndex, columnIndex) => {

    this.setState({
      isModalOpen: true,
      addWidgetOptions: {
        layout,
        rowIndex,
        columnIndex,
      },
    });
  }

  onMove = (layout) => {
    this.setState({
      layout: layout,
    });
  }


  onRequestClose = () => {
    this.setState({
      isModalOpen: false,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <Container>
      <AddWidgetDialog widgets={this.state.widgets} isModalOpen={this.state.isModalOpen} onRequestClose={this.onRequestClose} onWidgetSelect={this.handleWidgetSelection}/>
      <Header />
      <EditBar onEdit={this.toggleEdit} />
      <Dashboard
        frameComponent={CustomFrame}
        onRemove={this.onRemove}
        layout={this.state.layout}
        widgets={this.state.widgets}
        editable={this.state.editMode}
        onAdd={this.onAdd}
        onMove={this.onMove}
        addWidgetComponentText="Add New Widget"
        />

    </Container>
    );
  }

  toggleEdit = () => {
    this.setState({
      editMode: !this.state.editMode,
    });
  };

  handleWidgetSelection = (widgetName) => {
    const {layout, rowIndex, columnIndex} = this.state.addWidgetOptions;


    this.setState({
      layout: addWidget(layout, rowIndex, columnIndex, widgetName),
    });

    this.onRequestClose();
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Maintain a variable of the existing widget value.
When you add a widget, call removeWidget(layout, rowIndex, columnIndex, widgetIndex); with the existing value and after that, add like you are already doing.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing but I am fairly new to react and I am not sure how to implement this as there is no pre-existing removeWidget() method.

Comment: You can ask the dazzle developer to expose the removeWidget method. They already use it internally in edit mode. They have an onRemove method, but I don't think it does what we want it to do here.